# Connectivity issue in DB2

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

Getting the below error while trying to connect DB2 server from Debian GNU/Linux system.
Steps I have done

1. Installed ibm_db & ibm_db_sa module
2. Connected Python3.8 & imported ibm_db, which was succesful
3. Run this command >>> ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=DB;HOSTNAME=xx.xx.x.xxx;PORT=449;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=xxxxx; PWD=xxxxxx;DRIVER={IBM Db2 ODBC DRIVER}", "", "")

THe above command gives me below error, I have searched many articles and some are saying this is a network error which needs to be checked by the administrator and all, But the system connectivity is working fine. We are using a IPSEC tunnel for this and this tunnel destination is the DB2 IP & Source IO is the Ip we re using in the script.

We haven't installed any driver? Is it due to this? Is there any way or guidance to resolve this or to install a driver if it is required?

```
    Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  
Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "xx.0.x.xxx".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-30081
```

Comment: Any SSL/TLS involved (it would require more parameters)? Check the details in the docs: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=message-tcpip-errors

Comment: If you are tunnelling into Db2, most likely the tunnel is not operating on that port, or a local firewall is blocking traffic on that port, or wrong port specified. Always a configuration error...